# Is there any way to update SNS Topic policy through Java SDK?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-sns, aws-policies

I do have an SNS Topic in my AWS account, which I created through Java SDK, hence the policies attached are default policies.

**Is there any way to update the policy through java SDK itself?**

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the [`addPermission`](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/sns/SnsClient.html#addPermission(java.util.function.Consumer)) and [`removePermission`](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/sns/SnsClient.html#removePermission(software.amazon.awssdk.services.sns.model.RemovePermissionRequest)) methods with the [`PermissionRequest.Builder`](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/sns/model/AddPermissionRequest.Builder.html) to define the actions/principals

An example code snippet:

```
AddPermissionRequest addPermissionRequest = new AddPermissionRequest();
addPermissionRequest.setTopicArn("arn:aws:sns:....");
addPermissionRequest.setAWSAccountIds("arn:aws:iam::account:role/role-name-with-path");
addPermissionRequest.setActionNames("sns:Publish", "sns:GetTopicAttributes");

AddPermissionResult addPermissionResult = snsClient.addPermission(addPermissionRequest);
```